# libcublas.so.8.0 error with tensorflow

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am currently trying to run a project from GitHub: https://github.com/nilboy/pixel-recursive-super-resolution

After installing ubuntu on VM, I installed python with tensorflow 2.7 using the pip command.

When I try to run the training session with python I get this error:

***ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory***

I could't find anything exactly the same, only this error: 
**ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file**

I am using Yoga 13, so I don't have an NVIDIA GPU and I am trying to run this project on the CPU. Can you help identify the tensorflow problem?

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: Were you able to find a solution Shimron? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Caesar just use tensorflow-gpu 1.5 with cuda 9.0

Answer (score 12):

You need to install Cuda 8.0 and configure the environment as below:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64"
```

Answer (score 5):

may be preinstalled tensorflow-gpu, so

> pip3 install tensorflow --ignore-installed

as this helped me from stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you @nexoma. This worked for me. I have been at it since the past couple of hours.

Answer (score 2):

[Tensroflow/Keras requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)

In my opinion the tricky steps are installing Nvidia drivers and Cuda-8. If you follow the instructions you're gonna have a bad time. Instead install it thru `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 #can type nvidia then hit "tab" to view all available options
sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
```

If that doesn't work...good luck. You can try this:

Check that you do not have cuda-9: `ls /usr/local`

[Install Cuda 8.0.](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive)

Reboot

Run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but replace `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64` with the relevant output from `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Check that it worked `nvcc --version` prints out CUDA version

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while running Tensorflow with GPU support in Python and solved it like this:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin" 
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64"
```

For enabling all users you may have to enter these export statements in etc/environments in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with the CUDA version installed. try
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0

Answer (score 1):

On my computer I had :

```
cudnn5.1,   
cuda8.0
```

When importing tensorflow, I had the same error ImportError:

> libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

and even

> libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

To overcome this issue I installed `tensorflow 1.4` instead of 1.6 
 and did what Umair Qadir suggested.

But then I had another issue :

> libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

This was because I had cudnn5.1 as required but actually it needs cudnn6

Here are the steps to uninstall cudnn5.1 and install cudnn6:

1- Uninstall cudnn 5.1
    rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h
    rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn
    rm -f /usr/local/cuda-/lib64/libcudnn

2- Install cudnn6

After having subscribed to nvdia, go to here https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download and download cudnn6 for cuda8 and then go to the folder where you downloaded the cudnn and do :

```
$ tar xvzf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1-ga.tgz
$ sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
$ sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn /usr/local/cuda/lib64
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h 
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Now you should have tensorflow

Try it on typing in the console:

```
$python
import tensorflow
```

If you want to work in anaconda and the error persists , try :

```
$jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

then you can find the name of the directory where you have your config file (Ill call it

) and open /jupyter_notebook_config.py and add at the top :

```
import os
c = get_config()
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0'
c.Spawner.env.update('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Now it should work...

Here are the websites that helped me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/952075/how-to-upgrade-tensorflow-to-v1-3-cudnn-cuda-upgrade
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download
https://medium.com/@ikekramer/installing-cuda-8-0-and-cudnn-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-6b9f284f6e77
[tensorflow gpu can not be called from jupyterhub/jupyter notebook, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984135/tensorflow-gpu-can-not-be-called-from-jupyterhub-jupyter-notebook-why)