# After doing update and upgrade, now get tensorflow ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0 cannot

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I have a conda environment with tensorflow with GPU installed and running fine using CUDA 8.0. It was installed using pip and is version tensorflow-gpu 1.1.0. This is on Ubuntu 14.04. I have been using it for awhile now with no issues. Then I did a `sudo apt-get update` and a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and now get the following error when I try to import tensorflow into pytyhon:

```
> > In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in <module>()
>      40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
> ---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>      42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__
> 
> /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
> in <module>()
>      27             return _mod
> ---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>      29     del swig_import_helper
> 
> /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
> in swig_import_helper()
>      23             try:
> ---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,
> description)
>      25             finally:
> 
> /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py in
> load_module(name, file, filename, details)
>     241         else:
> --> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
> 
> /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py in
> load_dynamic(name, path, file)
>     341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
> --> 342         return _load(spec)
>     343 
> 
> ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory
```

I found the following related but no answer: [libcublas.so.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865253/libcublas-so-8-0-error-with-tensorflow), similarly this one with an upvoted answer that does not make sense to me: [other libcublas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924218/what-does-the-error-importerror-libcublas-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-fi). I am wondering how to fix this hopefully without going through a reinstall of all CUDA, CudNN, etc. Something in the update/upgrade broke this and evidently removed this file?

update: I made a clone of the conda environment and installed latest tensorflow 1.2.1 with GPU. Now I get the same error but different missing shared object file: `libcusolver.so.8.0`

Comment: Is libcublas.so.8.0 on your system?

Comment: I could not locate it using search.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libcublas8.0 ? what is it giving you?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libcublas8.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libcublas8.0'

Comment: seems you have to reinstall from source tensorflow again https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was  able to resolve this by only reinstalling Cuda 8.0. I did not have to reinstall CudNN or Nvidia drivers or tensorflow. Since my previous install was a deb install, I did not have to remove anything. I followed instructions at [cuda install](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4VZnqTJ2A). I believe that the update/upgrade and subsequent autoremove deleted the files in `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`. During the problem, this folder only had a few files in it and now there are many including the missing ones.