# Jupyter notebook cannot import caffe

Tags: plot, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, caffe

I work with caffe and I can run my python code and train network successfully. but I need to draw some plots interactively during trainig so I try to use jupyter notebook and IPython but jupyter cannot import caffe and raise this error:

ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any suggestion to solve the problem or to live plot without IPython??
Thank you!

Comment: Are your installation relying on different versions of python? If so, consider installing caffe on Jupiter environment

Comment: @DDS I installed jupyter on both version of python and got the same error

Comment: @SomayyehAtaeiKachouei this is not a jupyter notebook error, but error with tensorflow and CUDA drivers (for GPU support). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865253/libcublas-so-8-0-error-with-tensorflow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libcublas.so.8.0 error with tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865253/libcublas-so-8-0-error-with-tensorflow)

Comment: @DOS Thank you, but I check this links and also check my paths as I said I run caffe and tensorflow on my system but It's seems theres is a problem for IPython to recognize caffe

Answer (score 0):

Add  `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/caffe/path/caffe/python"` to the end of `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file.
After adding the above line to the file  `run` `source whichever file you have edited`.

If your are using `bash`,  `~/.bashrc` is to be edited and if your on `MAC`, `~/.profile` to be edited

For only one Jupyter Session

`import sys
caffe_root = '/home/basha/caffe/python'
sys.path.insert(0,caffe_root)
import caffe`

Comment: I did this all and as I said I am running caffe and tensorflow on my system but I think somthing about IPyhton and Jupyter goes wrong.

Comment: For me, running `python3` and then `import caffe`, works fine. running `jupyter notebook` and then `import caffe`, is what does not work. @SomayyehAtaei